# Why does this covariance matrix have a rank of $n$?

Tags: covariance-matrix

I'm reading [this paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In9yU.png), which contains the following covariance matrix:

[image: Covariance Matrix]

In the example there are six forecasters who estimate some quantity, and then we look at the covariances of those estimates.

I understand from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178587/why-is-the-rank-of-covariance-matrix-at-most-n-1) that the rank of a covariance matrix is at most $n-1$, and I also understand that the rank of a matrix is also equal to its number of nonzero eigenvalues.

I entered this covariance matrix into MATLAB and it says the rank of the matrix is 6. MATLAB says this matrix also has 6 nonzero eigenvalues. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse the *sample size* with the *number of vectors* for which you calculate the covariance.

You have $k=6$ forecasters, each of which provides some number $n$ of forecasts (which you don't give in your question). So you get a $k\times k$ covariance matrix, which can have a rank of at most $n-1$. But if $n>k$, then the matrix can certainly have full rank $k$, as it does here (it's block diagonal, and both blocks have nonzero determinant, so the matrix is nonsingular and has full rank).

Comment: There might not be any $n$ involved as this might not be a sample covariance matrix

Comment: It is a sample covariance matrix, though. Actually the example in the paper is hypothetical but they're referring to a situation which would in the regular course of events involve a sample covariance matrix.

Comment: Why is the rank tied to the number of forecasts $n$ rather than the number of forecasters $k$? I realise that it is true, but I don't understand why the number of forecasts should be relevant, since the size of the covariance matrix is completely determined by the number of forecasters.

Comment: @user1205901: that's exactly [the question you link to](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/178587/1352). See also [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/60622/1352), which the other one links to.

Comment: Thanks. Because the question I linked didn't have any answer I wasn't sure what to think of it, but the second link looks like it will resolve things.

Comment: @user1205901: I have now provided an answer to the question you linked to; you might be interested to take a look. +1 to Stephan's answer, by the way.