Proof in "Linear regression analysis" by Seber and Lee
In appendix result A.2.2, the authors want to show that:
If $A$ is any matrix and $P$ and $Q$ are any conformable nonsingular matrices, then $rank(PAQ) = rank(A)$
They start the proof by giving the following sequence of inequalities:
$rank(A) \leq rank (AQ) \leq rank(AQQ^{-1}) = rank(A)\quad\quad [1]$
Previously, in A.2.1 they have proven that if $A$ and $B$ are conformable matrices, then, $rank(AB) \leq \min({rank(A),rank(B)})$
While this result can be used to establish the later inequalities of $[1]$, it is not clear to me how the first inequality, $rank(A)\leq rank(AQ)$ is established. Is it a known result elsewhere that if $Q$ is nonsingular, $rank(A)\leq rank(AQ)$? Any simple enough proof of this result or a place where it is shown is much appreciated.
Here is an imgur link of their statement and proof of this result from their book, reproduced inline below:


This might be better for math exchange.

Once you understand that matrices represent linear transformations, this result is immediate, requiring no elaboration.  The proof is a matter of a diagram like the one appearing at the end of https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/180360/919.  The proof you quote simply sketches the relevant diagram (in algebraic notation) in case it wasn't obvious to the reader.

@whuber, I feel the signs in the text are problematic as Seber in his other book correctly stated. Correct me, if I am wrong.

@User1865345 Yes indeed--I wasn't paying attention to that, it's so obvious!  (This apparently glaring error doesn't change the argument or its conclusion and ought to be considered a mere typographical mistake.)

Interestingly the error/typo (as you rightly said) went unnoticed in Seber's Linear Model book too, surprisingly @whuber.

$\newcommand{\r}{\operatorname{rank}}$ Seber in his handbook mentions the result with the following proof:

Let $\bf A$ be any matrix.
If $\bf P$ and $\bf Q$ are any conformable nonsingular matrices, $$\r(\mathbf{PAQ}) =\r(\mathbf A). $$

Using the result in $\rm A. 2.1,$ he showed the proof as:

$$\r(\mathbf A) =\r\left(\mathbf P^{-1}\mathbf P\mathbf A\right)\color{red}{\leq }\r(\mathbf{PA})\leq \r(\mathbf A).$$

Following this, the result stated in Seber&Lee would be $$\r(\mathbf A) =\r\left(\mathbf{AQQ}^{-1}\right)\leq \r(\mathbf{AQ})\leq \r(\mathbf A).$$
--
Reference:
A Matrix Handbook for Statisticians, George Seber, John Wiley & Sons., $2007, $ p. $39.$

Ah. Thank you. Also, I add that it was your answer with reference to Seber and Lee to an earlier question of mine that nudged me to start using that book and proving results from there. So, thanks!

Nice to hear that. As for the proofs, the author has provided few in the edition.
